# modal image popups

Tags: javascript, image, modal-dialog

I have seen a few sites that have a thumbnail and when you click it, it enlarges the image in a modal like popup. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is done with [lightbox](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). There are several other scripts that do this, for example a [jquery plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) is an easy way to implement a modal popup. It is usually done using one of the many plugins.

- [piroBox](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/)
- [FancyBox](http://fancy.klade.lv/)
- [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)
- [nyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)
- [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

The list goes on and on. You can view the top 23 [here](http://www.blogrammierer.de/jquery-die-23-besten-bildergalerie-plugins/)

Answer (score -1):

you should also be able to do it with ajax in .net.  Here is a dialog box sample, you may be able to modify for your usage. http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx